# Variable scope related. Calling a variable in a function from a different fuction - unexpected behaviour/results

Tags: javascript

I am learning javascript and I tumbled upon this behaviour where it would not execute the function f2() at the end of the code.

```js
function f1() {
  var oneT = 55;
  console.log(oneT);
}
f1();
console.log(typeof(oneT));

function f2() {
  if (typeof(oneT) == undefined) {
    console.log("oneT can't be read outside the f1() as it's scope is limited to the fn f1().");
  }
}
f2();
```

If the **undefined** is not put in " ", then the f2() at the end is skipped (overlooked?). If put in " ", then it executes the f2().
Can someone explain to me the possible reason for this behaviour? Thank you in advance!

Comment: typeof returns a **string** ... `"undefined" != undefined`

Comment: The `if` is not fulfilled no matter whether you test `== undefined` or `== " "` (if that's what you mean), because the `typeof` something is always a *string*

Comment: Thank you. I understood now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing that because the `typeof` operator is returning you the value `"undefined"` as a *string*.

From the MDN [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof):

> The typeof operator returns a string indicating the type of the
>   unevaluated operand.

You can do a `typeof()` on top of `typeof(typeof(oneT))` to check that it is indeed returning you a string.

The `f2()` is getting called but you don't see any output as the `if` block is skipped entirely, because you are comparing a string `"undefined"` returned from the `typeof(oneT)` with the `undefined` value:

```js
function f1() {
  var oneT = 55; //function scope
  console.log(oneT);
}

f1();
console.log(typeof(typeof(oneT))); //string

function f2() {
  if (typeof(oneT) == undefined) { //false and if is skipped
     console.log("oneT can't be read outside the f1() as it's scope is limited to the fn f1().");
  }
  console.log("Inside f2"); //prints this
}

f2();

function f3() {
  if (typeof(oneT) === "undefined") { //true
     console.log("oneT can't be read outside the f1() as it's scope is limited to the fn f1().");
  }
}
f3();
```

Comment: You cleared all the confusion for me. I should've referred the MDN docs on JS earlier on the "typeof" subject. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`f2()` is executed every time, just the condition inside is not met. `== undefined` evaluates true if on the left side is a falsy value (0, empty string, null, false, undefined). `typeof` returns string `"undefined"` which is not empty string.

Comment: Thank you for correcting me on the part of f2() being executed. That helped.